# How to compare two Excel workbook, and if the data matches on both sheet, color code from second should automatically apply to first one

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, I want to compare both.

Want to compare workbook1, sheet1, column1 with workbook2,sheet1, column3

If the data matches between the column, color highlighting should be applied.

Data is in format of 0000.0000, e.g. 1234.0001

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. What have you tried so far and what research have you done?

Comment: i tried using various codes available in internet but nothings working for me, i tried posting those codes here, but lenght too long.

Comment: @Gareth i am new to vba thats why asking for help, if i knew how to do it, wouldn't have posted this question,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a code writing service

Comment: if you guys are not able to help, its okay. thnx alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
if workbooks("First_workbook address").sheet1.range("A1").value=
   workbooks("second_workbook address").sheet1.range("C1").value     
then    
   workbooks("First_workbook address").sheet1.range("A1").colour = vbRed    
Endif
```